# How to update SharePoint feature?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-feature

I've created and installed a custom Document Library as a feature to SharePoint (WSS3) installation. The installation and activation went fine and the feature is operational.

However, now I need to change the feature schema.xml file but I can't find a way to update the changes to SharePoint. I guess it's done via the stsadm.exe tool but can't find documentation on how to actually perform the update. Is there a simple to command to update the feature with FeatureId or name? Or do I need to deactivate and uninstall it before readding it to the site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to deactivate the feature, install an updated version, and then activate it again.

Comment: Short answer, but ok... As you asked about stsadm, you should look into the `-o upgradesolution` command for feature updates.

Comment: -o upgradesolution seems to require a solution file or something.. I just have a folder with bunch of xml files and other stuff in it. It's basically a copy of DocumentLibrary folder in ...\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\. I modified the required files to make it unique and renamed the copied folder.

Answer (score 0):

Following is relevant to 2010/2013.

Increment the feature version in your feature manifest (found in visual studio) then use PowerShell and run the following.

```
Update-SPSolution -Identity "My Awesome WebParts v1.wsp" -LiteralPath "C://My Awesome WebParts v2.wsp"
```