# How to Update SharePoint feature (List Template Views)

Tags: sharepoint

I have a sharepoint 2007 feature that contains a list template, however if I change my schema.xml the change doesnt apply

I tried deactivating and uninstalling the feature so i could install it again but that didn´t work. 
Also based on this question:
[How to update SharePoint feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304164/how-to-update-sharepoint-feature)
I tried modifying the Version in the feature and reinstall but that didnt work either

¿How can I accomplish a feature update?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I found that the only thing that isn't updating is the view element, I mean, if I change the display name it gets updated with the above procedure, but if I change a view it isnt updated

Answer (score 0):

With SharePoint 2007, the "Version" is not really useful.
Your problem is that the list based on your template is already "provisionned" : Is has been created with a certain version of your list template and is not updated when you update your list template. This is "By Design"
I think you have to create a new list based on your list template....

Regards,

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt work with new lists either, i made an edit to my question, basically the views are the ones that dont update